# Handling Apollo errors on the component side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

#### Question

How can I *react* to Apollo errors in my components?

I'd like for example to display a red banner if a "network offline" error was thrown; or show a modal if an error of a certain type is displayed; or render a `<Redirect>` (from `react-routed-dom`) if another kind of error is thrown.

#### What I tried

I read the documentation [chapter about error handling](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html) but it only explains how to setup an Apollo link that acts as a middleware to requests in order to catch errors there. As far as I know it's not possible to pass data from that link down to components given that it's a *terminating link*.

I tried to use [error boundary components](https://hackernoon.com/error-boundaries-in-react-16-32fb8e185a3) but it seems like Apollo errors are not really thrown. Not even when using the `await` syntax.

Comment: If downvoters would like to explain their downvotes that would be helpful.

Comment: Why would anyone give a downvote (actually 2) to a question?

Comment: There are trolls everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already pointed out, you could use the `apollo-link-error` package
[Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html).

If you also use `react-router-dom` for routing between pages, it is possible to use the browser history or the Redirect component to redirect to an error page with a state object ([routing history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)). The state object contains the error that you would like to show.

The setup could look like this:

- Create browser history

```html
import { History, createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
   
/* If using Typescript, you can make this object Readonly as follows */
export type ReadonlyBrowserHistory = Readonly<History>
const browserHistory: ReadonlyBrowserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

export default browserHistory;
```

- Add Router with browser history (*w/ option to make history properties readonly*)

```html
import browserHistory from './browserHistory'
import apolloClient from './apolloClient'

... 

ReactDOM.render((
   <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
         <App />
      </Router>
   </ApolloProvider>
), document.getElementById("root"));
```

- add link with routing to apollo client

```html
import browserHistory from './browserHistory'

const errorLink = onError(({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {
   if (graphQLErrors) {
      browserHistory.push("/error", { errors: graphQLErrors });
   }
   else if (networkError) {
      browserHistory.push("/error", { errors: networkError });
   };
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
   uri: httpUri
});

const httpLinkWithErrorHandling = ApolloLink.from([
   errorLink,
   httpLink,
]);

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
   link,
   ...
});

export default apolloClient;
```

- The error page can retrieve the errors from the route location prop

```html
const ErrorPage = ({ location: { state } }) => {

  console.log(state);

  return (<div>error page</div>)
};
```

Comment: This wouldn't allow me to simply mutate the state of the current page without redirecting. In all error cases I don't want to redirect to a whole new page. I just want to either show a modal error (which can be canceled) or a red banner on top to show the user that we are offline, but that it can still access the data that is in cache.

Comment: Yes you are right. If you want to handle a mutation differently you would have to use the `operation` property in the callback to not handle the general error handling. In the component where you use the mutation you could use the `.catch()` function of the Promise to handle the error and show a popup. Should i edit my answer?

Comment: If am using UseQuery how will i get the graphQL errors in functional component ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by setting the errorPolicy of the query to `none` then you can catch the `graphQLErrors` object thrown from the query.

**Example**:

```js
yourQuery()
    .then()
    .catch((error) => { error.graphQLErrors });
```